# how to align text right just using xml not java files (for preferences)?

Tags: android, xml, alignment, preferences

I have a problem.
due to some reasons i need to align the text of preferences to right without using java files. I want my content to be right-aligned in both English and Persian devices, so Android's native RTL support won't solve this issue.
is there any way to do that in xml files?
here is some parts of my settings.xml file:

`<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"><PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/settings_category_faboyic_title" android:key="@string/settings_category_faboyic">
<Preference android:title="@string/settings_show_user_first" android:key="@string/settings_get" style="?android:attr/preferenceStyle" />`

the title one (first one which is category name) is alined right itself, but the second one is alined left.

this xml file is located in xml folder. if there's no way to edit this xml file, is there any way to edit strings file located in values folder? (because the texts of these pereferences are in strings.xml)

tnx in advance

Comment: have you tried setting the gravity? `android:gravity=right` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use in the xml file the

android:layout_alignParentRight="true"